# Changing the current closure?

Tags: javascript, closures, this

I am trying to get some old code to work properly with minimal modification.  The code was written on the assumption that it would run from a particular context.  I have the context object.

Original code:

```
function oldExample(){
    console.log(window); //New Error: window is undefined
    console.log(gBrowser); //New Error: gBrowser is undefined
}
```

New, working code:

```
function fixedExample(){
    console.log(this.window);
    console.log(this.gBrowser);
}

//Elsewhere
function loadData(context) {
    fixedExample.call(context);
}
```

Notes:
1.  `loadData` and `oldExample` are defined in separate files.
2.  `context` has other children besides `window` and `gBrowser`; This is an example

Is there a way to transition my `oldExample` code to work properly without needing to stuff `this.` everywhere? I.e., how can I run oldExample in a different context?

Comment: What do you think of  `function fixedExample(window, gBrowser){ ... }` and `... fixedExample.call(context, this.window, this.gBrowser);`?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles: That would work, but I prefer to avoid exhaustively listing `context`'s children.  `window` and `gBrowser` are not the only children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know how to do this is to define the properties as variables of the current context:

```
var object = {gBrowser: 'test'};

function oldExample(){
    console.log(gBrowser);
}

var gBrowser = object.gBrowser;
oldExample();
```

This example outputs 'test'

But all this does is move the property access outside of the function definition, doesn't save you anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bind method in javascript.
fixedExample.bind (context);

Now you need not use 'this' inside fixedExample and can use window directly.

Comment: `fixedExample.bind(context)();` works, but `oldExample.bind(context)();` gives `ReferenceError: window is not defined`.  Am I missing something?